# How do you hide login information (esp passwords) in .emacs init file?

Tags: security, emacs

If you're using an extension or emacs mode (e.g. rcirc) that has auto-login or similar config to store username and password, how do you hide password and/or username info?

I'd like to do something similar to how you put a link to something like a .smbpasswd file in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard Emacs way is to put in `.authinfo.gpg`

```
machine www.example.com login itsme password secret
```

and to encode it using gpg. I didn't test it with rcirc, but both gnus and tramp use it.

You can also put the same information into `.authinfo`, using only chmod to protect-it, but it won't be as secure.

Reading the source of Emacs auth-source.el show that it can do quite complex thing, in particular, you could use `M-x customize-variable auth-sources` to choose different way to specify login/mdp to Emacs (including gnome and kde stuff).

Comment: Out of curiosity: do these Emacs extensions require this file to be named `.authinfo`, or do they accept `.netrc` as well? Several other Unix tools use `~/.netrc`, which has the exact same syntax.

Comment: @grawity: I do not know, but you can create a symbolic link nevertheless.

Comment: You can change the `auth-sources` Emacs variable to point to the file you use. Its default value is `("~/.authinfo" "~/.authinfo.gpg" "~/.netrc")` meaning that .netrc will be looked at.